# Summing a pandas series

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sum, series

I got a pandas Series object, which looks like this:

```
(Pdb) PiECoS  
t   sit    com      com_type  
1   South  Coal     Stock       2.0  
1   Mid    Solar    SupIm       4.0  
2   South  Coal     Stock       1.0  
2   Mid    Solar    SupIm       0.0  
                               ...
10  South  Coal     Stock       0.0
10  Mid    Solar    SupIm       0.0

Name: sub_commodity_source, Length: 300, dtype: float64
```

Expected Output:

sum all of the t=1 to 10 and add it to t=10

```
t   sit    com      com_type  
1   South  Coal     Stock       2.0  
1   Mid    Solar    SupIm       4.0  
2   South  Coal     Stock       1.0  
2   Mid    Solar    SupIm       0.0  
                               ...
10  South  Coal     Stock       3.0
10  Mid    Solar    SupIm       4.0
```

or

```
t   sit    com      com_type    
10  South  Coal     Stock       3.0
10  Mid    Solar    SupIm       4.0
```

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: I tried doing this PiECoS['Total'] = PiECoS.sum(), I think it works but could be also better I don't really want a Total row. About the pic, man I am sorry. I tried to copy paste the whole series object, but needed to fix too many new line problems.

Comment: @Robᵩ fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you are asking, you want to sum all values with regards to the t index:

```
s.groupby(['t','sit','com','com_type']).sum().reset_index()
```

Comment: 1 / Mid / Hydro / SupIM + 2 / Mid / Hydro / SupIm + ... + 10 / Mid / Hydro / SupIm = 10 / Mid / Hydro / SupIm

Comment: s.sum(level=['t','sit','com']) ?

Comment: Same this time "1   Mid    Biomas..." as extra

Comment: @Icedkk I don't understand what you are looking for. Could you create a small dataset sample and what the expected output should be?